# Convert windows relative path to linux relative path

Tags: python-3.x

Given the windows relative path that always starts with a directory name e.g.:

```
a\\b\\c
```

I want to convert it to linux style path path:

```
a/b/c
```

taking into consideration all the possible differences between path formats (if any).

Comment: `s = s.replace("\\", "/")`

Comment: If you are creating the path yourself you might want to look into [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PathLib : https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

The side of yours \ will be replaced by /.
So you can use / with Windows as UNIX path